# Meteor Date for ease of sorting

Tags: javascript, meteor

Often I enter a filed `createdAt = new Date()` in the Meteor collections, which looks like this

> "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-03T10:00:49.192Z")

Wouldn't it be easer for sorting if the formate is the number of seconds since 1970 instead? and if so, what is the efficient way to insert such formate instead of converting the current formate? thanks

**edited**
After Salman solution, I tried to apply the "same" idea for no avail.

In the browser console,

```
x
Object {_id: "m3FMayA33R4Y2FgbD", action: "ation1", createdAt: Thu Mar 03 2016 22:00:36 GMT+1100 (AEDT)}
x._id.getTimestamp
undefined
```

Comment: Why would you change date format? If you sort be createdAt field it'll work just fine.

Comment: @Fred Sorry for the incorrent solution

Comment: A date is really turned into an [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Date/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [moment js](http://momentjs.com/)  to format date time. :)